# How to create marquee on text block in windows phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone, marquee

i'm trying to create marquee but i don't have proper idea how to create so any 1 knows then please help me.

```
  <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,24,0">
        <Canvas x:Name="myText" >
            <TextBlock  HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="293,156,0,0"/>
        </Canvas>
```

now how to give marquee i dont know.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Blend to do the animation. In blend, select the textblock, set start position. In timeline, record a new position and in code behind start the storyboard. The article at http://www.fantageek.com/66/wp7-how-to-create-marquee-textblock/ may help you.

Hope it helps.